# Security stamp validator in jwtBearerMiddleware

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, authorization, jwt, asp.net-core-identity

I've a oauth2 resource server which uses the `JwtBearerMiddleware` to validate the access tokens. Now I wan't that the access token is invalid if the security stamp has changed. As it looks like this middleware doesn't validate the security stamp by itself.

I've found the `SecurityStampValidator` class which only seems to validate cookie authentication.

Where and how do I have to validate the security stamp from my json web token?

---

My current way to do it is to register an eventhandler for the `OnTokenValidated` event when I register the `JwtBearerMiddleware`. In this eventhandler I simply query the database for the security claim and compare it with the one in the token. When the security stamp isn't the same I just set the `Ticket` and `SecurityToken` of the context to `null` and skip to the next middleware which eventually will throw an 401 http status code if authentication is required.

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    ...
    Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async (ctx) => 
        {
            var securityStampClaim = ctx.Ticket.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp");
            var subjectClaim = ctx.Ticket.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject);

            if (securityStampClaim == null || subjectClaim == null)
                return;

            var user = await userStore.FindByIdAsync(subjectClaim.Value, ctx.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            if (user?.SecurityStamp == securityStampClaim.Value)
                return;

            ctx.SecurityToken = null;
            ctx.Ticket = null;
            ctx.SkipToNextMiddleware();
        }
    }
});
```

Is this how it should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this how it should be done?

Technically, yes (you could even use `SignInManager.ValidateSecurityStampAsync(principal)` to simplify your code a bit).

That said, **you should strongly consider avoiding storing the security stamps** in your JWT tokens because they are not just "opaque" strings used to determine whether a token or a cookie should be considered as revoked, they are also used as the sole source of entropy by ASP.NET Core Identity to generate 2FA tokens: if you store them as-is in a JWT, they can be easily extracted by a malicious third-party client application and used to predict valid 2FA codes for the logged in user.

This is a known issue, but AFAIK, there's no plan to fix it: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/626.

If you want to store the security stamps in your access tokens, consider using OpenIddict's default (encrypted) format, which is exactly the same as the one used by ASP.NET Core for its encrypted authentication cookies.

Comment: why does asp identity store the Security stamp in the Claims principle then?
and isn't it not efficient to make a trip to the database with every request to validate the stamp?

Comment: Note: The mentioned issue was fixed in 2.1.0

Comment: So now is it safe to add it to the jwt token?

Comment: If your JWT tokens are not encrypted (typically using JWE) OR if you don't own the resource servers that consume them, then no, it's not safe. The ASP.NET team opened a separate ticket to consider fixing that in a future version, but it's in the backlog, so chances are high it won't be fixed before a while: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5772

Comment: @KévinChalet The security stamp not created with `Guid.NewGuid()` anymore. It should be safe to return now. https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/pull/1714/files

Comment: Besides the code which creates a guid on linux changed as well and guarantees now some more entropy and shouldn't create guids which identify the system they are made on or similar stuff. In the worst case it uses srand48/mrand48 now. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/pal/src/misc/miscpalapi.cpp

Comment: @NtFreX "it should be safe to return now"... I disagree: 1) the fact GUIDs are guaranteed to have enough entropy for being used even in crypto scenarios is definitely not new (it was already true in 2015). 2) the security stamp is still used for TOTP: if you don't keep it secret, your application is at risk.

Comment: I guess better be safe then sorry also for the future. Encrypting should not hurt. At least the change should mean I can now return `Guid.NewGuid()` for other use cases from my auth server to non trusted clients and do not have to fear that my security tokens and by extend my TOTP's can be calculated. If I understand that right.